# Just display the one result PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which display a list of players and their points in a contest:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <?php
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pointstable` WHERE `contestfield` = 1 ORDER BY `pointsfield` ASC");
    while ($info=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $playerid=$info['playeridfield'];
        $playername=$info['playernamefield'];
        $pointsfield=$info['pointsfield'];
     ?>

  <tr><td style="text-align:center; padding-bottom:5px" valign="middle"><?=$playername?> made <?=number_format($pointsfield)?></td></tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

This will display the complete list, but when a user plays more than one time, it displays all the points he has...

So what I want is to display only the first value (in this case, the lowest points since the objetive of the contest is to get the lowest score) The **playeridfield** is a unique number for each player, each player has one.

Who can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the mysql `min` function and group by id:

```
SELECT playeridfield, playernamefield, MIN(pointsfield) AS pointsfield FROM `pointstable` 
WHERE `contestfield` = 1 GROUP BY `playeridfield` ORDER BY `pointsfield` ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Ad this to your SQL query at the end LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your SQL query to this:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pointstable` WHERE `contestfield` = 1 ORDER BY `pointsfield` ASC LIMIT 1");
```

The `LIMIT 1` should make it so only one row is returned from the query.

Comment: I would even go so far as `LIMIT 0,1` to ensure the offset puts is set for the top row.

Comment: The default offset is 0.